# NHibernate bi-directional association

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to model a parent/child association where a Parent class (Person) owns many instances of a child class (OwnedThing) - I want the OwnedThing instances to be saved automatically when the Person class is saved, and I want the association to be bi-directional.

```
public class Person
{
        public class MAP_Person : ClassMap<Person>
        {
                public MAP_Person()
                {
                        this.Table("People");
                        this.Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Access.BackingField();
                        this.Map(x => x.FirstName);
                        this.HasMany(x => x.OwnedThings).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().KeyColumn("OwnerID").Inverse();
                }
        }

        public virtual Guid ID { get; private set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<OwnedThing> OwnedThings { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
                OwnedThings = new List<OwnedThing>();
        }
}



public class OwnedThing
{
        public class MAP_OwnedThing : ClassMap<OwnedThing>
        {
                public MAP_OwnedThing()
                {
                        this.Table("OwnedThings");
                        this.Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Access.BackingField();
                        this.Map(x => x.Name);
                        this.References(x => x.Owner).Column("OwnerID").Access.BackingField();
                }
        }

        public virtual Guid ID { get; private set; }
        public virtual Person Owner { get; private set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I set Person.OwnedThings to Inverse then the OwnedThing instances are not saved when I save the Person.  If I do not add Inverse then the save is successful but person.OwnedThings[0].Owner is always null after I retrieve it from the DB.

**UPDATE**
When saving the data NHibernate will set the single association end in the database because it is set via the many-end of the association, so when I retrieve the OwnedThing from the DB it **does** have the link back to the Person set.  My null reference was from Envers which doesn't seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I understanding you correctly that your problem only occur on "history" entities read by nhibernate envers?

If so, it might be caused by this bug
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE-64
The workaround for now is to use Merge instead of (SaveOr)Update.

Answer (score 0):

`OwnedThings[0].Owner` is most likely null because you are not setting it when you do the add.  When using bidirectional relationships you have to do something like the below:

```
Person person = new Person();
OwnedThing pwnedThing = new OwnedThing();

pwnedThing.Owner = person;
person.OwnedThings.Add(pwnedThing);
```

If you do not explicity set the `pwnedThing.Owner` and you query that same object in the same `ISession` that you created it on it will be null.  Typically I have add or remove methods that do this "extra" work for me.  Take the below example:

```
public class Order : Entity
{
    private IList<OrderLine> orderLines;
    public virtual IEnumerable<OrderLine> OrderLines { get { return orderLines.Select(x => x); } }

    public virtual void AddLine(OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        orderLine.Order = this;
        this.orderLines.Add(orderLine);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveLine(OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        this.orderLines.Remove(orderLine);
    }
}

public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        DynamicUpdate();
        Table("ORDER_HEADER");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ORDER_ID");

        HasMany(x => x.OrderLines)
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .KeyColumn("ORDER_ID")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```